# CURL Getting error CURLE_PEER_FAILED_VERIFICATION (60)

Tags: c, ssl, curl, ssl-certificate, libcurl

I am using CURL to connect with ssl in a ftpserver.
Doing this i am using code below

```
curl_easy_setopt( hCurl, CURLOPT_USE_SSL, CURLUSESSL_ALL );
//curl_easy_setopt( hCurl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE );
//curl_easy_setopt( hCurl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE );
curl_easy_setopt( hCurl, CURLOPT_CAINFO, HostCertificatePath );
curl_easy_setopt( hCurl, CURLOPT_URL, strServerIP );
```

The path to the certificate is correct, absolute, and refer to the public key of the server.
Using it with filezila allow me to access to the server.

The certificate looks like this :

```
subject=C = mycountry, ST = mystate, L = mycity, O = myorganization, CN = *.mydomain.org
issuer=C = mycountry, O = myorganization, CN = mycompany

-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
*******************************************
*******************************************
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

and i get the error CURLE_PEER_FAILED_VERIFICATION (60).

If i try to uncomment CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST = FALSE i still have this error

If i try to uncomment CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER = FALSE i got the error CURLE_SSL_CACERT (51)

If i try to uncomment both i got back the error 60.

I have no clue about what to do, and none of the other post on the subject helps me. (Most of them resolve the issue by adding CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER = FALSE, or updating ca)

Thanks for any help you could give to me.

Comment: Related, all VERIFYHOST does is ensure (1) the host certificate subject and/or SAN contains the site/ip you're connecting to, and (2) the presented certificate is trusted by the CA bundle you point at with CAINFO. In short, you trust the host if it matches who it claims to be *and* its presented cert is signed by someone you trust. The CAINFO doesn't contain the host cert; it contains the public side of the signing CA cert that *signed* the host cert. You could also use CAPATH, but that requires hashing the folder using ca_hash once all your PEMs are in place.

Comment: @WhozCraig thanks alot for those informations.
As you said, the cainfo is the public key of the host certificate. I used it with filezilla so i think it is working as you describe it. But i don't understand the hasing part of your awnser
About the host, i knew i could have issue with CM=*.mydomain.org that's why i tried to put VERIFY_HOST to false, but that doesn't fix the problem.

Comment: @WhozCraig About your 2nd point, if i am in an internal network, without a way to reach the CA bundle who signed the certificate, how can i tell curl to not check it and just trust me.